# How to remove two backslashes and add only one in a string in c#?

Tags: c#, uwp

This string "\uf461" is getting converted into "\uf461" string. I tried to replace but it's not working.

```
str = str.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

I have stored all font awesome icons (class name, unicode) in a dictionary and trying to set a text property in a xaml code

```
 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.test}"
```

and trying to bind it to

```
test = dict[classname];
```

but it gets convert into "\uf461" string instead of "\uf461" and then code doesn't display

[Here in question when i submit the question two black slashes are automatically getting converted into one]

Comment: it will never work for the "\uf461" as it contains only one backslash symbol

Comment: then how do I set its value? Is there any way i can show this icon?

Comment: The `\uf461` is a font awesome icon called "Allergies" is that ok? Not sure what you want to achieve, you mean that when there is a `\uf461` in a given string, then in your app it should be displayed as an icon instead of the value, correct?

Comment: if you want to display the font awesome icons nicely in the UWP app I'd suggest taking a look at [this open-source library](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF/blob/master/README-UWP.md) If it's about it, I'd also suggest editing your question to better explain your real issue and what you really want to achieve.

Comment: yes. That's correct. I have stored all font awesome icons (class name, unicode) in a dictionary and trying to set a text property in a xaml code                                                                    
  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.test}"  and trying to bind it to                                                   
   test = dict[classname]; but it gets convert into  "\\uf461" string instead of "\uf461" and then code doesn't display

Comment: it should have two slashes if it's in a c# string.  backslashes are escape characters and to put one in a string, you need to escape it with a second one.  It NEEDS two of them to contain one.  Also if you are putting html rendering code inside a text string and then adding it with razor or viewmodels, you need to wrap it in Html.Raw or the compiler will garble all the characters into utf-60.

Comment: but Html.Raw will not work in uwp code

Comment: When I added the "\uf461" into Dictionary and access it to assign to the text of TextBlock, it didn't convert to two backslashes, can you please provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?